# Sort a Result set according to a property value of 'parent' property.Please read the details

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table/result set like:

```
Name |  Property_Name  |  Property Value

Jack      School          public school
Jack      Age             12
Jack      Parent          Julia   
Mary      Parent          Samantha
Mary      School          Brookes School
Mary      Age             8  
Julia     Occupation      Teacher
Julia     Age             32    
Julia     Salary          3000
Jone      School          private school
Jone      Parent          David
Jone      Age             10
David     Occupation      Plumber
David     Age             35
David     Salary          2500 
Samantha  Occupation      Nurse
Samantha  Salary          3500
Samantha  Age             30
Samantha  Parent          Peter
Peter     Occupation      Retired
Peter     Age             59
Peter     Salary          0
```

I want the result set to be sorted as `parent-child-child, parent-child, parent child` and so on.
That is , the result should be like:

```
Name |  Property_Name  |  Property Value

Peter     Occupation      Retired
Peter     Age             59
Peter     Salary          0
Samantha  Occupation      Nurse
Samantha  Salary          3500
Samantha  Age             30
Samantha  Parent          Peter
Mary      Parent          Samantha
Mary      School          Brookes School
Mary      Age             8  
Julia     Occupation      Teacher
Julia     Age             32    
Julia     Salary          3000
Jack      School          public school
Jack      Age             12
Jack      Parent          Julia
David     Occupation      Plumber
David     Age             35
David     Salary          2500
Jone      School          private school
Jone      Parent          David
Jone      Age             10
```

As you can see, the rest of the properties are irrelevent. Only condition is all the rows of a person should be grouped, and child rows should immediately follow its parent's rows(if any), this parents rows should follow the 'super parent'(if any) rows. 
  
 
What should be the best approach for this? Any help would be highly appreciated .
   Apologies if it is a duplicate, pleaase point me out if any.

Comment: Poor design, nice problem to solve.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a script for inserting test data.

Comment: Not really poor design, if you consider there are actually hundreds of properties for each "person", and the properties also varies from region to region, language to language etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this(I add one more child to Julia for more cases. She has 2 children now)

```
 with t(Name,Property_Name  , PropertyValue) as (
select 'Jack',      'School',          'public school' from dual union all
select 'Jack',      'Age',             '12' from dual union all
select 'Jack',      'Parent',          'Julia' from dual union all 
select 'Mike',      'School',          'public school' from dual union all
select 'Mike',      'Age',             '15' from dual union all
select 'Mike',      'Parent',          'Julia' from dual union all   
select 'Mary',      'Parent',          'Samantha' from dual union all
select 'Mary',      'School',          'Brookes School' from dual union all
select 'Mary',      'Age',             '8' from dual union all  
select 'Julia',     'Occupation',      'Teacher' from dual union all
select 'Julia',     'Age',             '32' from dual union all   
select 'Julia',     'Salary',          '3000' from dual union all
select 'Jone',      'School',          'private school' from dual union all
select 'Jone',      'Parent',          'David' from dual union all
select 'Jone',      'Age',             '10' from dual union all
select 'David',     'Occupation',      'Plumber' from dual union all
select 'David',     'Age',             '35' from dual union all
select 'David',     'Salary',          '2500' from dual union all 
select 'Samantha',  'Occupation',      'Nurse' from dual union all
select 'Samantha',  'Salary',          '3500' from dual union all
select 'Samantha',  'Age',             '30' from dual union all
select 'Samantha',  'Parent',          'Peter' from dual union all
select 'Peter',     'Occupation',      'Retired' from dual union all
select 'Peter',     'Age',             '59' from dual union all
select 'Peter',     'Salary',          '0' from dual),
    parents(name) as
     (select distinct name
        from t parent
       where not exists (select *
                from t all_rec
               where all_rec.Property_Name = 'Parent'
                 and all_rec.name = parent.name)),
    hierarhy(name,
    parent,
    lv,
    rn) as
     (select alls.*, level, rownum as rn
        from (select name, null as parent
                from parents
              union all
              select name, PropertyValue
                from t childs
               where Property_Name = 'Parent') alls
      connect by parent = prior Name
       start with parent is null
       order siblings by name desc)
    select t.*
      from hierarhy, t
     where hierarhy.name = t.name
     order by hierarhy.rn, hierarhy.lv, t.Property_Name, t.PropertyValue
```